# keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer equivalent in Pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, pytorch

Basically the title; is there any equivalent to`keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` in Pytorch? I have yet to find any that gives all the utilities without handcrafting things.

Comment: Especially when looking for equivalents, it is helpful to link any resources that explain the function in question in a little more detail, e.g., a pointer to the Keras documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find Torchtext more difficult to use for simple things. [PyTorch-NLP](https://github.com/PetrochukM/PyTorch-NLP) can do this in a more straightforward way:

```
from torchnlp.encoders.text import StaticTokenizerEncoder， stack_and_pad_tensors, pad_tensor

loaded_data = ["now this ain't funny", "so don't you dare laugh"]
encoder = StaticTokenizerEncoder(loaded_data, tokenize=lambda s: s.split())
encoded_data = [encoder.encode(example) for example in loaded_data]

print(encoded_data)
```

> [tensor([5, 6, 7, 8]), tensor([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])]

```
encoded_data = [pad_tensor(x, length=10) for x in encoded_data]
print(stack_and_pad_tensors(encoded_data))
# alternatively, use encoder.batch_encode()
```

> BatchedSequences(tensor=tensor([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]), lengths=tensor([10, 10]))
>   ​

It comes with other types of encoders, such as spaCy's tokenizer, subword encoder, etc.

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch itself does not provide a function like this, you either need to it manually (which should be easy: use a tokenizer of your choice and do a dictionary lookup for the indices).

Alternatively, you can use [Torchtext](https://github.com/pytorch/text), which provides basic abstraction from text processing. All you need to do is create a [`Field`](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#field) object. You can use `string.split`, SpaCy or custom function for tokenization. You can provide a vocabulary or create it directly from data. Then you just call [the `process` method](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Field.process) which tokenizes text and does the vocabulary lookup.

If you want something more complex, you might consider using also [AllenNLP](https://allennlp.org/). In AllenNLP, you do separately [the tokenization](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.data.tokenizers.html) and [the vocabulary lookup](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.data.vocabulary.html).